# How to make calabash-ios tests run within CircleCI?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, calabash, calabash-ios, circleci

How can you run calabash-ios tests within CircleCI?

This is what I have tried:

```
machine:
  xcode:
    version: "6.3.1"

dependencies:
    override:
        - sudo gem install calabash-cucumber
        - sudo gem install cocoapods


test:
    overrride:
        - pod setup
        - pod install
        - calabash-ios gen
        - cucumber
```

And after installing calabash, CircleCI does not end up running the commands written in my .feature file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing to this:

```
machine:
  xcode:
    version: "6.3.1"

dependencies:
    override:
        - sudo gem install calabash-cucumber
        - sudo gem install cocoapods


test:
    pre:
        - pod setup
        - pod install
    post:
        - cucumber
```